# Using functions within conditionals

Tags: javascript, function, conditional-statements

I've been doing Project Euler 'cause reasons. At one point, I found myself wanting to compare a value with the result of a function. I've since selected a different solution, but it's left me curious. How would this work? If I were to do something like:

```
//javascript
if x == mathyFunction(10){
  //do this
}

function mathyFunction(y){
  if(y>0){
    mathyFunction(y-1);
    return y;
  } else {
    return y;
  }
}
```

I'm aware that this isn't tail recursive or anything fancy, I'm mostly just curious how the logic works behind this.

How would the computer interpret it? Would it return `true` if any one of the values `== x` or would it only return true if all the values `== x`. Experimentation has left me guessing, though I'll keep digging.

Comment: From your code, I see the mathyFunction winding the 10 value down to zero and always returning 0. Then comparing it to x, and if x isn't 0 then it would be false.

Comment: @nocturns2 It's not returning 0, it's returning `y`.

Comment: You're right. I was referring to the value of y, which would be what you would be comparing to the value of x.

Comment: @nocturns2 `x` is compared to 10 as that's the value that's passed in for `y`.

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure if your code will even work. it should be `mathyFunction(y){ return y>0? mathyFunction(--y) : y }`

Comment: I believe that x would be compared to the result of the mathyFunction, regardless of the parameter value.

Comment: @nocturns2 Yes, and the result is 10 because mathy returns its parameter value.

Comment: Yes because you are returning `y`. So recursion is left useless. Current implementation is similar to `mathyFunction(y){ return y }`

Comment: You're right @sepp2k, it would just return the original value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify which language you're asking about, but assuming the usual semantics of the `return` statement, a function can't return more than once. So if by "return all values individually", you meant something like this:

```
function f() {
  return 1;
  return 2;
  ...
}
```

Then everything after the first `return` is just dead code and it's the same as if the `return 1` was the only `return` statement in there. A function call has exactly one value and that value is what you're comparing against.

If you meant that `mathyFunction` returns a list or other collection object, which contains the values between `x` and `y`, then `x` will be compared to that list. Again the semantics will depend on the language, but in most languages comparing a number to a list will either be a type error or just `false`.

If by returning the values individually you were referring to a yield statement (like C#'s `yield return` or Python's `yield`), then the result of the function is going to be some kind of iterator object and the same thing as in the previous paragraph applies.

Comment: Apologies, I should've been more specific. It's javascript. The code behind `mathyFunction` is recursive, so it recurves  and then returns a value. I've modified the example slightly to reflect this, and I've changed `mathyFunction(x,y)` to `mathyFunction(x)` for simplicity.

Comment: @Ucenna The function in your edited question is the identity function. In both cases of the `if` all you do is return `y`. In the then-case you also call the function recursively, but since you don't do anything with the recursive call's result, that doesn't do anything (except make the code take longer unless the JavaScript engine manages to optimize that call away). Again: a function call can't return more than once - recursion does not change that.

Comment: Okey dokey then! I was working my way to that conclusion. What you've said aligns perfectly with my results.